# How do I uninstall ubuntu on my external HDD?

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I have ubuntu 10.04 Netbook Edition and I don't like its interface compared to desktop and it makes my laptop slow. I want to uninstall it but I don't know how to? Its installed to my 1TB external HDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed it using Wubi, you can uninstall Wubi from control panel. If not, you can safely format your hard disk partition to remove it. Just make sure that you backup all your data first.